# Problema tildes y acentos gutenberg al cambiar a modo bloque en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, caracteres

no encuentro solucion por ningún sitio de internet.

Al pasar a la versión de gutenberg se quedaron paginas en versión 4.9 y las nuevas paginas en modo bloque con la versión 5.1.1, todo bien hasta el momento, el problema lo he tenido cuando una pagina antigua de la versión 4.9 la he querido pasar a modo bloques para añadir nuevo contenido.

El problema es que esa pagina ahora muestra unos caracteres extraños que no consigo arreglar ya que he probado a desactivar todos los plugins por si había alguno que me diera conflicto.
Por internet hay muchas web que te recomiendan cambiar el CHARSET en el wp-confif.php para pasar de UTF8 a latin1, etc, etc.
He probado varios charset y ninguno me lo soluciona, ademas que esta modificación en el wp-config.php afecta a todas las paginas y entradas. Y yo solo tengo el problema en una pagina nada más, el resto de paginas se ven bien las tildes y acentos.

Si alguien tiene algo parecido y ha podido solucionarlo, le rogaría que me diga como lo ha realizado, ya sea tocando código o creando nuevos bloques o yo que se.

Podéis ver que solo afecta a la pagina Home, en el siguiente enlace https://www.lahormigablanca.com/ y con utf8 por defecto ya que deje el código tal y como estaba al principio.
Y aquí podéis ver como las tildes siguen funcionando bien https://www.lahormigablanca.com/tipos-de-hormigas/ con la misma codificación utf8 ya que afecta a todas las paginas.

Un saludo a todos y gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

He entrado al portal y lo he visto solucionado. Según veo que comentaste la misma pregunta en otro foro y al no poner la solución te la han solicitado. Tomaré tu solución (aunque para mí carece de sentido) y la publicaré por si otro usuario se enfrenta al mismo problema:

> La solución al problema no tiene mucho sentido, pero he quitado un
>   target=»_blank» de dos href y me ha resuelto el problema.
>
> He podido dar con el problema comparando el código fuente de dos
>   paginas (la que tenia errores y otra que no) aunque ademas me ha
>   ayudado que hace unas semanas introduje un botón en html (en otra
>   pagina totalmente distinta a estas dos) con el target=»_blank» e
>   inmediatamente me pintaba mal las tildes, por lo que le quite el
>   target=»_blank» pero no me acordé hasta ayer mientras los comparaba.
>
> El caso es que esta resuelto pero sin conocer el porque ocasionaba
>   este error.

Fuente: Foro [Wordpress.org](https://es.wordpress.org/support/topic/problema-tildes-y-acentos-al-cambiar-a-modo-bloque-gutenberg-una-pagina/)